# Ionic native Media Capture captureVideo duration not working

Tags: ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 **Media Capture** plugin to record a video with a maximum limit of 30 seconds.

**captureVideo** method's duration works well with devices greater than Lollipop, but not for devices with Lollipop or lesser versions.

Below is my code -

```
uploadVideo() {
   let options: CaptureVideoOptions = {limit:1,duration:30,quality:80};
   this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options)
   .then((data: MediaFile[]) => {
        console.log("Do Something.");
    },(err: CaptureError) => {
        console.log("Show Error.");
    });     
}
```

The same code stops recording after 30 seconds on Lollipop devices.
Is this an issue with the plugin or am I doing anything wrong here?